# Why does res.render() not output error page?

Tags: javascript, express

Having difficulty getting res.render() to output my designated error page. But when i use res.send() as shown in the code below, I can see the error message outputed to the browser. But when i use res.render('no-user', {error: 'no user found'});, All i get is a blank page on the browser even though the jade error page to which I am referencing is working correctly and intact.

```
router.get('/:questionnaireId', function(req, res, next) {
  Questionnaire
    .where({
      username: req.params.questionnaireId
    })
    .exec(function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        return next(error);
      }
      if (!result.length) {
        res.send('user not found');
      }
      res.render('user_home', {
        result: result
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: are you sure you have jade file name 'no-user' when using `res.render('no-user', {error: 'no user found'});`?

Comment: Do you see a `404 no-user` on your console?

Comment: No I don't see a 404 no-user. I have a jade file name 'no-user'